# Formatting double as a function parameter

Tags: java, number-formatting

I have a function that takes in a double as a paramater. However, if I input "8" when I call the function, it processes as "8.0".

I know that I can format it with `String.format()` and other methods, however the format that the number is inputted as is important to the result (8 has a different result than 8.0, and I have no idea inside of the function body which one was intended by the user).

I know that I can add a format parameter as well as the double, `function(double d, DecimalFormat f)`, but that would make it much more tedious to use, and it is intended as a util function anyways. Any tips?

Comment: Formattong turns it into a string. What's the actual *issue*? Why is the answer different for 8 vs. 8.0? What's the function's purpose?

Comment: maybe a bit of context / real cases might help :-)

Comment: `if I input "8" when I call the function, it processes as "8.0"` -- No it doesn't; it processes it as an [IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64).  `8.0` is a *display representation;* you can make that floating point number look any way you want when you display it.

Comment: *"the format that the number is inputted as is important to the result"* Why?!? `8`, `8.0`, `8e0`, `800e-2`, ... all represent the **same numerical value**, which is **8**. Numbers don't have a format, so the format *cannot* be "important".

Comment: @Andreas We don't know what the OP is actually doing, but the *precision* of 8 and 8.0 is different--this may be what the OP is trying to communicate. Maybe.

Comment: Just for clarification, the calculations I am doing with the input relates to the significant figures in the number, which is why 8 is different than 8.0 and 8.00. Yes, any operations with it would compute the same, but the rounding is affected.

Comment: @gooby If you need to control the *precision* (aka significant figures, aka scale, aka number of fractional digits) and do *rounding* on operations, **use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead of `double`**, where the objects `new BigDecimal("8")`, `new BigDecimal("8.0")`, and `new BigDecimal("8.00")` would all `a.compareTo(b) == 0` with each other, but `a.equals(b) == false`, because the [`scale()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#scale--) of the 3 numbers are different.

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways you can solve this, depending on your problem.

1. Method overloading

If the user input is by code, you can handle different types using the same method name.

```java
class Program {
    public static void foo(int n) {
        // The input is an integer
        System.out.println(n);
    }

    public static void foo(double x) {
        // The input is a double
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo(8); // prints 8
        foo(8.0); // prints 8.0
    }
}
```

2. Handling strings

However, if the user input is by keyboard, for example, you can use RegEx.

```java
class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = s.nextLine();

        if (input.matches("^\\d+\\.\\d+$")) {
            // The input is a double
        } else if (input.matches("\\d+")) {
            // The input is an integer
        } else {
            // The input is something else
        }
    }
}
```